# How do I get access to the `GitExtension` type documented in the vscode readme?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

The git extension built in to vscode has a type interface documented in it's readme; https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/tree/master/extensions/git
However, it's very unclear how an extension trying to use the extension would get access to the type.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [other plugins accessing that type](https://github.com/search?q=vscode.extensions.getExtension%3CGitExtension%3E&type=Code).

For instance: [`maixiaojie/git-emoji`](https://github.com/maixiaojie/git-emoji) in [`src/extension.ts`](https://github.com/maixiaojie/git-emoji/blob/f6ffa0ae0863cef60e5175bbbbb3661a5b08527c/src/extension.ts#L39-L43)

```
function getGitExtension() {
    const vscodeGit = vscode.extensions.getExtension<GitExtension>('vscode.git');
    const gitExtension = vscodeGit && vscodeGit.exports;
    return gitExtension && gitExtension.getAPI(1);
}
```

used as:

```
    const git = getGitExtension();
    if (!git) {
        vscode.window.showErrorMessage('unable to load Git Extension');
        return;
    }
```

Comment: So it looks like they copied the entire interface into their repo, which seems to be what gitlens did as well. Is there no way to reference it from node modules?

Comment: Not that I know of.